# Is there any way to put gatekeeping in Perforce for code checkins?

Tags: version-control, perforce

Looking to know if there is any way, that I can add gatekeeping rules to prevent code from getting checked in until there is atleast 1 approval on the CL?

I am not looking to add locks, as that prevents anyone from doing code changes.

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution is to use Swarm (a free tool that integrates with Perforce) for code reviews:

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/swarm/Content/Swarm/home-swarm.html

Swarm tracks reviews of shelved changelists, and comes bundled with pre-submit triggers that block submit until the changelist has been approved.